# How to say "please do not slam the door" in German?

Tags: translation

How to say "please do not slam the door" in German?

I tried to translate it like this:
"Bitte knall die Tür nicht zu", but there must be another way because I googled it with no result.

Comment: http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&client=opera&hs=4au&channel=suggest&q=%22knall+die+T%C3%BCr+nicht+so%22&spell=1&sa=X&ei=WWMyUb7XLpP74QTUxoGgAQ&ved=0CDAQBSgA

Comment: You should provide the context for this sentence. The two current answers are both correct but j0chn's is better if you talk to someone and knut's is better for a sign to be put on a door.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s what I would say to my kids if they go mental:

> Knall die Türe doch bitte nicht so zu!

If there is some adult running around slamming doors, I would try first to be a bit more polite:

> Kannst du die Türe auch leise zumachen? Danke!

Which indicates to him I am a bit pissed off about his habit how he is dealing with doors.

Or even more formal if we on 'Sie' level:

> Bitte machen Sie die Türe doch bitte das nächste Mal ein bisschen leiser zu.

Answer (score 6):

Your translation is pretty good.
another example is "Bitte schlag die Tür nicht zu". 
 Another translation but just in context not in words: "Mach die Tür leise  zu."

Answer (score 4):

You could say it with the opposite:

> Bitte die Türe leise schließen.

or shorter:

> Bitte Tür leise schließen.

Comment: While this is essentially a different sentence this is what is the "common" form to say this in german. This way is more polity than the asked phrase.

Comment: This "verbale Wortkette" is especially common when written on a sign.